# Magento: Use Web Server Rewrites is broken

Tags: .htaccess, magento, url-rewriting

Some time importing a project on my local machine it happens that the `Use Web Server Rewrites` feature doesn't works.

This is probably due to some `.htaccess` custom setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue on my case was this line in `.htaccess` file:

`RewriteBase ...`

commenting it out `#` fixed the issue